# (swiper) how to make large center slide, but not to overlap previous and next slide?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I'm building gallery-like slider for my web page and I need its slides to be centered (with larger active slide). I found [this](https://codepen.io/intotheprogram/pen/GRrOjVB) example on Codepen and it looks fine, except that active slide overlaps previous and next slides:

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    centeredSlides: true,
    loop: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesPerView: 1.5,
    spaceBetween: 40,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
    },
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    breakpoints: {

        640: {
            slidesPerView: 2.5,
        },
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 2.75,
        },
        1080: {
            slidesPerView: 3.25,
        },
        1280: {
            slidesPerView: 3.75,
        },
    },
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0;
    padding: 45px 0;
}

.swiper-slide {
    opacity: 0.4;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .7s;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide-active {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/6.8.4/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//into-the-program.com/demo/images/sample010.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//into-the-program.com/demo/images/sample005.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//into-the-program.com/demo/images/sample012.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//into-the-program.com/demo/images/sample007.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//into-the-program.com/demo/images/sample008.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//into-the-program.com/demo/images/sample009.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

It's clear that it acts that way because of scale(), but I couldn't find any better solutions. I've tried to use slidesPerView: 'auto' and to set width to slides, but then active slide won't be centered due to it's dynamic width change.
Is there any solution for this? I would really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

Push active slide and next one, by margin-left, NOT right (in active, for example)

```
.swiper-slide-active {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: scale(1.5);
    margin-left: 70px;
}
.swiper-slide-next{
    margin-left: 70px;
}
```